# What is a fewnomial?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, polynomials, terminology

I came across the theory of "fewnomials" (by Khovanskii), which (I guess) are related to polynomials. However, I was surprised that there is no single question on stackexchange concerning fewnomials, and few in mathematical research in general (there are some papers on arXiv). Does anyone know something more about the concept and can please explain me the idea behind fewnomials? Thanks.

Comment: i believe polynomial where only very few coefficients are nonzero, e.g. $x^{13} - x - 1 = 0$

Comment: Dunno, but clearly they ought to have been named *oligonomials*!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why oligonomials? btw. in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4548.pdf they say that they can be called also "sparse" or "lacunary" polynomials.

Comment: Khovanskii generalized Descartes bounds on the number of real roots of a polynomial to systems of multivariate polynomial equations. The bounds are useful primarily for polynomials with few monomials "fewnomials". A web search should turn up many expositions (besides Khovanskii's book).

Comment: @pisoir: Because *poly-* in *polynomial* is from the Greek prefix πολυ-, from πολúς ‘many’, whose opposite is ολιγο-, from ολίγος ‘few’. But I was joking, because *polynomial* itself is a hybrid formation: the *-nomial* element is from Latin, not Greek.

Comment: It's a nomial that has an unpleasant odor. Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pep%C3%A9_Le_Pew

Comment: Maybe ask about it in mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Fewnomials come up in my bachelors thesis. I will try to explain where they come from. I think this will give you the idea. Although Bezout's theorem bounds the number of complex solutions of a system of multivariate polynomial equations in terms of degrees, it usually highly overestimates the number of real zeros (see Descartes' rule of signs). In 1980 Khovanskii generalized Descartes' rule. He showed that the number of nondegenerate positive solutions of a system of $n$ real polynomial equations in $n$ variables is bounded only in terms of $n$ and the number $t$ of distinct exponent vectors in the system.
With this in mind, one calls a system of polynomial equations, where $t$ is small a "fewnomial system". Understanding the positive solutions is in general very hard, but note that the above statement assures that if we have given a fewnomial system, we at least do not have "many" solutions.
Working with fewnomials as it turns out is much simpler. An example of a very powerful result in fewnomial theory is the Bernstein–Khovanskii–Kushnirenko (BKK) theorem.